# How to display the switch as on or off based on the value in database

Tags: flutter

Here I have a switch. If it is 'on' remind me field in table is set to 1 else 0. Now when I open this screen for editing then it should pre populate but I dont know how to do it for switch I have tried this but its not working.

```
bool isSwitched=false;
  var textValue = 'Switch is OFF';

  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    if(note.rmnd_ind==0)
      isSwitched==false;
    else
      isSwitched==true;
    if(isSwitched == false)
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = true;
        note.rmnd_ind=1;          
      });
    }
    else
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = false;
        note.rmnd_ind=0;
      });
    }
  }
```

..

```
Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Remind me",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:80.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Switch(
                          onChanged: toggleSwitch,
                          value: isSwitched,                                          
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],),
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a comparison where you should do assignation. And you're not using the value param anywhere.

```
if(note.rmnd_ind==0)
    isSwitched==false; // should be isSwitched = false
else
    isSwitched==true; // should be isSwitched = false
```

try this:

```
void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
        isSwitched = note.rmnd_ind==0;
        setState(() {
        if(isSwitched == false)
        {  
            isSwitched = true;
            note.rmnd_ind=1;           
        }
        else
        {
            isSwitched = false;
            note.rmnd_ind=0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: tysm for correcting me. Silly me. I tried your code but still its not working

Comment: onChanged:  => toggleSwitch(value here?),